# How can I resolve "message": "google is not defined"? (Google MAPS API)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, backend

```
const axios = require('axios');

const HttpError = require('../models/http-error');

const API_KEY = 'AIzaSyCCyuG9sL_7IXBkooXVPX74HzkrO5CzklQ';

async function getCoordsForAddress(address) {
  // return {
  //   lat: 40.7484474,
  //   lng: -73.9871516
  // };
  const response = await axios.get(
    `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=${encodeURIComponent(
      address
    )}&key=${API_KEY}`
  );

  const data = response.data;
  if (data === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    const error = new HttpError(
      'Could not find location for the specified address.',
      422
    );
    throw error;
  }

  const coordinates = data.results[0].geometry.location;

  return coordinates;
}

module.exports = getCoordsForAddress;
```

in this location file, a given address will be given and geocodig api send the latitude and longitude of this given address

```
{
    "title":"Empire State Building",
    "description": "A very famous building in new york",
    "address": "11 Wall St, New York, NY 10005, United States",
    "creator": "u2"
}
```

Then I got this error

```
{
    "message": "google is not defined"
}
```

I am trying to catch geo coding locations of a given address

Comment: Have you included libraries? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/libraries?hl=en

Comment: @k102 yes i have include all librarries